# Combining two apps in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-project

I have two Xcode workspaces, both the workspaces have multiple targets. Each target in both the workspaces have storyboard file called Main.storyboard. My problem is to combine one target in the first workspace with a second in another. What is the right approach to merge the targets?

Answer (score 0):

The target configuration is in `***.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file. You can just copy and paste what you need.